# WebP library for C#

Tags: c#, jpeg, webp

It seems like there is no code samples for WebP in C#. Is there any? I don't need to display WebP images directly but saving & transferring as WebP would be nice.

Comment: Did you find anything for this?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at http://webp.codeplex.com/. There is a library that allows you to easily encode into WebP format. Check out this question for more information:

[Convert Bitmap to WebP Image?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13220436/convert-bitmap-to-webp-image)

The library allows you to save into WebP format like so:

```
using (Image image = Image.FromFile("image.jpg"))
{
   Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
   WebPFormat.SaveToFile("image.webp", bitmap);
}
```

Comment: is there something similar for java/android?

Comment: This project looks abandoned...

Comment: Throwing format error.http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43677838/c-sharp-webp-image-throwing-error-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an

Comment: Google Chrome doesn't shows the webpage because of security warning on the webp.codeplex.com link.

Comment: I think that it is moved to: https://github.com/imazen/libwebp-net

Answer (score 7):

WebP-wrapper

Wrapper for libwebp in C#. The most complete wapper in pure managed C#.
Exposes Simple Decoding API, Simple Encoding API, Advanced Encoding API (with compresion statistics), Get library version and WebPGetFeatures (info of any WebP file). In the future I´ll update for expose Advanced Decoding API.
The wrapper is in safe managed code in one class. No need for external dll except libwebp_x86.dll and libwebp_x64.dll (included v6.1). The wrapper work in 32, 64 bit or ANY (auto swith to the apropiate library).

The code is full comented and include simple example for using the wrapper.

Comment: I needed a way to convert .webp images to .jpg images and it works great.

Comment: It doesn't work, just throws exception during WebPGetFeatures WebPGetFeaturesInternal_x64, impossible to debug further because it's a dLL, moreover the error message simply gives the name of the DLL file!

Comment: There is literally not a single example of anyone in the world trying to use this DLL in Unity C#.

Answer (score 5):

**there is a project in github**

> Wrapper for libwebp in C#. The most complete wrapper in pure managed C#.
>
> Exposes Simple Decoding API and Encoding API, Advanced Decoding and
>   Encoding API (with stadistis of compresion), Get version library and
>   WebPGetFeatures (info of any WebP file). Exposed get PSNR, SSIM or
>   LSIM distortion metrics.
>
> The wrapper is in safe managed code in one class. No need external dll
>   except libwebp_x86.dll and libwebp_x64.dll (included v6.1). The
>   wrapper work in 32, 64 bit or ANY (auto swith to the apropiate
>   library).
>
> The code is full comented and include simple example for using the
>   wrapper.

see project page: https://github.com/JosePineiro/WebP-wrapper

Answer (score 1):

There is https://github.com/mc-kay/libwebp-sharp wrapper project. But it doesn't seem to be implemented.

Comment: https://github.com/imazen/libwebp-net