# Convert Bitmap to WebP Image?

Tags: c#, bitmap, image-conversion, webp

Anyone know if it's possible to convert a `Bitmap` to a `WebP` image using C#?

Been Google-ing around but wasn't able to find anything for C#. I found this:
[mc-kay/libwebp-sharp · GitHub](https://github.com/mc-kay/libwebp-sharp) but it doesn't seem to convert bitmaps to the `WebP` format.

Any ideas?

Answer (score 0):

Download libwebp dll [here](https://www.dll-files.com/libwebp.dll.html). (There are 32-bit and 64-bit formats). Copy dll file to your **bin** folder (in local path and release folder)

Then, in your project, install **Imazen.WebP**

Code snippet :

```
using Imazen.WebP;

string folderPath = "C:/MyImages";
string webpFileName = "image123.webp";
Bitmap mBitmap = new Bitmap(img);

using (var saveImageStream = File.Open(folderPath + webpFileName, FileMode.Create)) 
{
    var encoder = new SimpleEncoder();
    encoder.Encode(mBitmap, saveImageStream, 75); // 75 is Image quality
}
```

Hope this help !