# C# WebP image throwing error "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format."

Tags: c#, webp

I am try to convert jpeg image to webp format. like below in console application

```
    using (Image image = Image.FromFile("Capture.jpg"))
    {
        Bitmap bitmap = new Bitmap(image);
        WebPFormat.SaveToFile("image.webp", bitmap);
    }
```

Reference from here

http://webp.codeplex.com/

Below details of error

> **Error:** An unhandled exception of type 'System.BadImageFormatException' occurred in
> Noesis.Drawing.Imaging.WebP.dll
> Additional information: An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format.
>
> **ErrorMessage** : An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect
> format. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007000B)
>
> **StatckTrace:**    at Noesis.Drawing.Imaging.WebP.NoesisWebP.Save(IntPtr& oWebPFileImage,
> Int32& oWebPFileImageSize, IntPtr iBitmap, Int32 iWidth, Int32
> iHeight, Int32 iQuality)    at
> Noesis.Drawing.Imaging.WebP.WebPFormat.Save(Int32 iQuality, Bitmap
> iImage)    at Noesis.Drawing.Imaging.WebP.WebPFormat.SaveToFile(String
> iFilename, Int32 iQuality, Bitmap iImage)    at
> WebP.Program.Main(String[] args) in
> c:-----\Program.cs:line 17    at
> System.AppDomain._nExecuteAssembly(RuntimeAssembly assembly, String[]
> args)    at System.AppDomain.ExecuteAssembly(String assemblyFile,
> Evidence assemblySecurity, String[] args)    at
> Microsoft.VisualStudio.HostingProcess.HostProc.RunUsersAssembly()
> at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.RunInternal(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean
> preserveSyncCtx)    at
> System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Run(ExecutionContext
> executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)    at
> System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()

Comment: `WebP` From Noesis is no longer maintained and the last release was a beta release 7 years ago. Consider using another framework for your conversion.

Comment: Duplicated of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11370344/could-not-load-file-or-assembly-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-a You are mixing 32 bits and 64 bits assemblies

Comment: Possible duplicate of [I get a "An attempt was made to load a program with an incorrect format" error on a SQL Server replication project](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/41449/i-get-a-an-attempt-was-made-to-load-a-program-with-an-incorrect-format-error-o)