# Convert a JPG or PNG to WebP in C# .NET 6

Tags: c#, asp.net-core, .net-6.0, webp, imagesharp

I am working in a .NET 6 application. I am already aware of the [following answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/54136197/how-to-convert-jpg-to-webp-in-c-sharp), but I was looking for a solution where I wouldn't have to install `.dll` and manually include it in my project.

That answer is from 2019, and I was wondering if there's a better, easier way of converting a `.jpg` or `.png` to `.webp`.

The user is uploading an image file `IFormFile` and I am using ImageSharp to process the image (e.g. re-size it ...etc)

```
Image standardImage = Image.Load(file.OpenReadStream());
standardImage.Mutate(x => x.Resize(300, 300));
```

Before uploading the image to S3, I want to convert it to `.webp`. Is there a better way than the answer linked above?

Comment: This should help https://blog.elmah.io/convert-images-to-webp-with-asp-net-core-better-than-png-jpg-files/

Comment: This is still the same question, which is already answered. If the answers don't suit your needs, add a bounty asking for a better answer - you have plenty of reputation to use. Also, as it is, this is just a recommendation request, which is off-topic as you should know

Comment: My bad @CamiloTerevinto. Apologies, I'll do better next time. Thank you.

Comment: ImageSharp V2 will support WebP. Format support is already available in development builds.