# Is it possible to read WebP images into a C# Bitmap object?

Tags: c#, .net, asp.net-core, webp

I am using .NET Core 3.0 MVC app with a file upload for users. These files assumed to be an image, but for obvious reasons, I validate the image before saving it to the server.

Now I have ran into an issue, when a user tries to upload a JPEG image (which seems to be fine as he had to email it to me for further inspection) and this image seems to be a WebP image or was converted from a WebP Image.

The issue is that one of the check for each image is

```
using (var bitmap = new Bitmap(postedFile.OpenReadStream()))
{
}
```

This threw an exception "Parameter is not valid" and because of this, validation fails.

If I read the buffer of the uploaded `IFromFile`, it starts with `RIFFڶ\0\0WEBPVP8`

This is how I knew, this is not a normal image.

Any way to decode or validate this image as any other?

Comment: Do you actually need to read the image? WebP is not supported by `Bitmap`. [There are libraries which can](https://stackoverflow.com/q/7566426/215552), but if you don't actually need to manipulate the image, I suggest just looking at the `Content-Type` HTTP header.

Comment: I dont think `Content-Type` and `Header` would be enough to check if the file is valid. I check those libraries though. Thanks

Comment: From [here](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/framework/winforms/advanced/types-of-bitmaps?view=netframework-4.8), you can find the supported formats are BMP, GIF, EXIF, JPEG, PNG and TIFF.

Answer (score 2):

I use [Magick.NET](https://github.com/dlemstra/Magick.NET)  to convert WebP images to PNG's (single frame) or GIF's (animated). My code looks like:

```
public static Bitmap NewBitmap(this FileInfo fi) {
    Bitmap bitmap = null;
    try {
        bitmap = new Bitmap(fi.FullName);
    } catch (Exception) {
      // use 'MagickImage()' if you want just the 1st frame of an animated image. 
      // 'MagickImageCollection()' returns all frames
        using (var magickImages = new MagickImageCollection(fi)) {
            var ms = new MemoryStream();                    
            if (magickImages.Count > 1) {
                magickImages.Write(ms, MagickFormat.Gif);
            } else {
                magickImages.Write(ms, MagickFormat.Png);
            }
            bitmap?.Dispose();
            bitmap = new Bitmap(ms);
            // keep MemoryStream from being garbage collected while Bitmap is in use
             bitmap.Tag = ms;
        }
    }
    return bitmap;
}
```

It's not superfast, especially for GIF's with many frames, but works well.

Answer (score 1):

Now to be clear, you probably shouldn't be using `System.Drawing` on web server apps, there are plenty of cross-platform imaging APIs out there like `ImageSharp` [that support modern formats out of the box](https://docs.sixlabors.com/articles/imagesharp/imageformats.html) and allow you to read, identify, edit and stream images over network streams efficiently.

However, `System.Drawing.Common` [does support WebP starting from .Net7](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.drawing.imaging.imageformat.webp?view=windowsdesktop-7.0), though of course only on Windows, since it uses GDI+ internally, and only in Windows version 10.0.17763.0 or newer.